# ffmpeg record screen file formats

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, screen-recording

Good day,
I'm currently writing a bash script which records the screen under certain conditions. The problem is that only avi works as a file extension for recording the screen. This script is going to be used on an Raspberry Pi and currently I get on a decent virtual machine only 10-20 fps (goal would be around 30 fps). I think .avi is not suited for my project. But .mpeg and .mp4 are not working for recording. I tried recording with .avi and then converting it in .mp4, but I have limited memory and .avi ist just too big in size. I use currently the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -y -r 30 -s 960x750 -i :0.0+0,100 -vcodec huffyuv ./Videos/out_$now.avi
//$now is the current date and time
```

So I wanted to know if I need some special packages from ffmpeg to record with for example .mp4 or if there are other file formats available for ffmpeg screen recording.

Edit:
I found that the codec libx264 for mp4 works, but the fps drop until they hit5 fps, which is definetly too low. The recorded video appeared like being a fast forward version of the recorded screen.

With mpeg4 for mpeg I reached over 30 fps, but the video qualitywas very bad.

It appears that even my big avi-files look like being played fast forward. Is there something I do wrong?

Is there a good middle way, where I get a decend video quality, good fps (20+) and a file which isn't too big?

Edit 2:
I tried recording it with .avi and converting it afterwards. Just converting with `ffmpeg -i test.avi -c:a aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -crf 23 output.mp4` 
resulted in the same framedrops as if I was recording with .mp4. But when I cut a littlebit of the beginning of the video and named the outputfile .mp4, the size became much smaller. But when I started the cutting at 0:00:00 (so tried just converting), it just changed the file format without converting it (so the size stayed the same). Any ideas?

Comment: Show your command encoding with libx264 and the complete log.

Comment: Can't reproduce with ffmpeg version 4.2.1-0, are you using an old version?

Comment: @llogan `ffmpeg -f x11grab -y -r 30 -s 905x675 -i :0.0+9,155 -c:v libx264  ./Videos/out_$now.mp4`
And what do you mean "the complete log"? What the output in the console is?
@oguzismail: ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0

Comment: @New_Dev After you run the ffmpeg command in your command-line interface it will output information in your command-line interface. This information is required to provide answers for ffmpeg usage. [Here is an example from another user](https://pastebin.com/raw/yHr0uJRm).

Comment: I guess you mean the log when recording with libx264:
[log](https://pastebin.com/raw/ZFD04J0d)